# integrate ffmpeg with spring boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, ffmpeg

I have a react native app much like social media app.Users upload their photos and videos from that app .While uploading I wanna show processing sign with percent and I have RESTful api endpoints written in spring boot and wanna resize media(photos and videos).Is there any easy way to implement it.I have heard of ffmpeg but I don't know how to integrate it with spring boot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> At its core, FFmpeg is program itself, designed for command-line-based processing of video and audio files, widely used for format transcoding, basic editing (trimming and concatenation).

Hence you could call it by using `System.call` command line from your java Spring boot App.

```
// Just one line and you are done ! 
// We have given a command to start cmd
// /K : Carries out command specified by string
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/K", "Start"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But how can we know how much time does it gonna take to convert as we wanna show processing sign with percent in our mobile app.

Comment: @ParkashSbd welcome! But your original question doesn't talk about the processing and percent sign. Please edit the question or ask another one.

Comment: Thanks for you advice.I have also edited my question and do you know how can I achieve it.

Comment: See there is third party [utility](https://github.com/althonos/ffpb), but I have never used it.

Comment: welcome, you could accept my answer if it helps you!